# Model updates in directive do not update view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .component('sideNav', {
    controller: function SideNavController($scope) {
    $scope.navigation = {};
    $scope.click = function(key) {
      $scope.navigation[key] = !$scope.navigation[key];
    }
  },
  templateUrl: 'components/side-nav/side-nav.html',
})
```

to be used as simply

```
<side-nav></side-nav>
```

The template is

```
<!-- other li items -->
<li ng-init="navigation.charts = false" 
  ng-click="click('charts')">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> 
      Charts {{ navigation.charts }}
      <span class="fa arrow"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav nav-second-level"
    ng-show="navigation.charts">
    <li>
      <a href="charts.html">Charts</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="graphs.html">Graphs</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

navigation.charts is correctly initialized to false and hence the li > ul is hidden. Clicking the top level li item updates the navigation object but the view does not update. I was expecting the li > ul element to get displayed.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UJpdFErwVUzsCd65hlW0?p=preview

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: try `$timeout(function() { $scope.$apply() })`

Comment: @charlietfl here's a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/UJpdFErwVUzsCd65hlW0?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on the link reloads the page and re-initializes the directive. Try modifying to:

```
<li ng-init="navigation.charts = false" 
    ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); click('charts')">
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Why does clicking the link reinit the directive? Would it be better then if I take out ng-init and initialize the values in the directive's controller?

Comment: I believe it is because of the route configuration. Clicking on the `<a href="#">` changes the hash to #, a route *"navigation away"* event. The router has no mapping for it and goes to `otherwise`, i.e. the existing view, but after destroying and initializing anew.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add **href="javascript:void(0)"**

```
<ul>
 <li ng-click="click('charts')">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> 
    Charts {{ navigation.charts }}
    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
</a>
<ul class="nav nav-second-level"
  ng-show="navigation.charts">
  <li>
    <a href="charts.html">Charts</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="graphs.html">Graphs</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This actually happens as you put href="#" which I think refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem. Can I just remove the href altogether?

Comment: You can remove a tag if you don't require than you have to add some css to provide hover on the text. As soon as you remove href tag. It wont show any hover effect.